# Php system() / exec() don't return output

Tags: php, command-line, exec

For common commands like 'ls', exec() works fine, eg:

```
exec('ls',$output,$retval);
var_dump($output,$retval);
// $output contains an array of filenames, and retval === 0
```

But when trying to execute another program, I can't get the output:

```
exec('some_command --a_parameter',$output,$retval);
var_dump($output,$retval);
// $output contains an empty array, end $retval === 0
```

This command prints some lines when executing it directly from the command-line though.
I know the command has been successful because of the results (some files updated, data added, etc), and yet I can't see the output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the command you issue actually print any output ?

Comment: It does when doing it directly from the command line. I mean I can see some lines of text appearing in the screen. Maybe there are different types of output?

Comment: What is the actual command you're running, please?

Comment: its just a program I downloaded, not a linux thing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like the program is outputting its warnings to standard error rather than standard output.  `exec` will only catch standard output.  I don't know for certain that standard error is always sent to the apache error log, but it seems likely.

If you don't need compatibility with non-*nix systems, you can redirect standard error to standard output by appending `2>&1` to the command:

```
exec('some_command --option 2>&1', $output, $ret);
```

This should both make the warnings available to your php program and prevent unnecessary logging.

Comment: add 2>&1 but output still is array empty, if execute from cmd , it output 2 values

Comment: Hmm could be that the command only outputs if its output is directed to a terminal. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

All the output was being sent to httpd/error_log when for some *** reason, when the application found a warning (something internal, not even fatal)

My solution: When there is no output, assume it failed.
My apache logs are going to get dirty, but whatever.