# How to interface PHP front-end with makefile/bash script?

Tags: php, bash, codeigniter, interface, makefile

I'm writing a project to manage multiple SSH tunnel via *CLI* and a web UI.

### Bash script

The service is written in `Bash` and can:

- `start` a given tunnel or all tunnels,
- `stop` a given tunnel or all tunnels,
- `status` of a given tunnel or all tunnels,
- `list` all tunnels available.

### Makefile script

The `makefile` can do some *"administrative"* tasks:

- `add-host` add config for a tunnel,
- `remove-host` add config for a tunnel,
- etc.

### Web UI

I want to create a web interface –using `PHP`/`CodeIgniter`–  to control the service.

### Question

- How can I interface *CodeIgniter* with makefile and bash command ?
- Specifically how do I use exit status to give information to the PHP script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `exec` ([docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)) command will probably do what you need.

You can run your scripts using `exec` and capture both the output of the script and the exit code. For example:

```
$output = array();
$exitCode = null;

exec("/path/to/my/script arg1 arg2 2>&1", $output, $exitCode);
```

`$output` will be an array of strings - the lines from the script's output. `$exitCode` will be the exit code returned by the script.

Note, however, that use of `exec` raises some concerns:

1. security - you must be careful to ensure that the user of your app cannot execute arbitrary code on your server.
2. permissions - commands run via `exec` will be run as the web server user; for Apache on Debian/Ubuntu this will be `www-data`.

Comment: 1) that's why I use the `makefile` and a service, they abstract the action I want to execute. 2) guess I will have to edit the `sudoers` to allow Apache to execute my service then.

Comment: I had trouble trouble at first due to privileges-related error. Only the first row was printed. I solved it by redirecting the command as follow: `exec('/etc/init.d/mast list 2>&1', $output, $exitCode)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5602987/802365