# displaying errors when executing a python script from php with system, in a shared hosting (other output is displayed)

Tags: php, python, debugging

I'm executing a python script from php with way,

> $mystring = system('python test.py', $retval);

and it works, I just would like to see error messages from the python script. Is it possible? It is returning output, for example, I see a "print "hello"" from the python script, but I dont see errors from the python scripts, it's obviously failing to load a module because execution stops there and I dont see that error displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php system() / exec() don't return output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602627/php-system-exec-dont-return-output) and there are others. In essence, try: `$mystring = system('python test.py 2>&1', $retval);`instead. This mixes stderr and stdout.

Comment: Actually, it returns output, for example, if the python script has a print I see it, but I can't see errors. I see "prints" before an import error but not after, and the import error message isnt displayed

Comment: Yes, and that is where the `2>&1` comes into play, it tells the system to write all that is intended for file descriptor 2 (the standard error stream out) instead to fd 1 (which is standard output if no one fiddles with it ;-) ). Please try the comment/answer and if it does what you want, enjoy and report back here. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it.. with the last option I dont see output at all :)

Comment: What underlying shell on that hosting platform? Can you for testing log in via ssh and try in that folder directly a `python test.py 2>&1` versus a `python test.py 2> /dev/null` and maybe show the python code here in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use in PHP:

```
exec('python test.py', $outp, $return);
```

You will have at `$return` the error status returned by the python script (there is an error if is not 0), and the error text at the `$outp`