# ffmpeg find duration of ogg file in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

From below command:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/f593599f005cc1ed453c0e92c37236063e6144b0-1480310327986/audio/audio.ogg  2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//"
```

Output is:

```
00:07:10:00
```

When I Put this command in php

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i /var/bigbluebutton/published/presentation/f593599f005cc1ed453c0e92c37236063e6144b0-1480310327986/audio/audio.ogg  2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//",$result);
```

It doesn't give any output.

Comment: if I used this command  echo exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes 2>&1", $result); then its give output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php system() / exec() don't return output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602627/php-system-exec-dont-return-output)